# Не записываются заголовки в csv файл

Tags: python

```
Сейчас заголовок записывается только в последний csv файл  noncontr_lv.csv
Как сделать чтобы заголовки записывались во все файлы  ?
```

```
мой код :
```

```
import ast
import csv

def contract_lv(list_d, write_header):
    with open('contract_lv.csv', 'a+', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as file_lv:
        writer = csv.writer(file_lv, delimiter=";")
        if write_header:
            writer.writerow(['Customer ID'])
        print(final_date['CustomerId'], file=file_lv, sep=';')


def post_lv(final_date, write_header):
    with open('post_lv.csv', 'a+', encoding='utf-8',newline='') as file_post_lv:
        writer = csv.writer(file_post_lv, delimiter=";")
        if write_header:
            writer.writerow(['CardNumber'])
        print(final_date['CardId'], file=file_post_lv, sep=';')


def noncontract_lv(final_date, write_header):
    with open('noncontr_lv.csv', 'a+', encoding='utf-8',newline='') as file_noncontr_lv:
        writer = csv.writer(file_noncontr_lv, delimiter=";")
        if write_header:
            writer.writerow(['Agreement Nr'])
        print(final_date['AgreementID'], file=file_noncontr_lv, sep=';')


with open('2222222.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    write_header = True
    for line in lines:
        final_date = ast.literal_eval(line)
        if final_date["ContractType"] == "Yes": 
            contract_lv(final_date, write_header)
            write_header = False
        elif final_date["ContractType"] == "Yes":
            post_lv(final_date, write_header)
            write_header = False
        elif final_date["ContractType"] == "None":
            noncontract_lv(final_date, write_header)
            write_header = False
```

Comment: А для чего Вы такой огород нагородили ввиде комбинации writer.write_row() и print to file?

Comment: @Namerek  наверное из-за того что я дилетант.

Comment: Еслия я правильно потнимаю, то логика того, что Вы пытаетесь воспроизвести заключается в следующем: Есть некий скрипт, который генерит данные, которые нужо собрать в csv файлы, при этом если файл существует, нужно дописать данные, а если нет, то создать файл и вписать заголовки и добавить строку с данными. Так?

Comment: @Namerek  идея  такая ,  скрипт создает файл ,  данный код его рассфасовывает по csv  файлам согласно условиям.  CSV файлы каждый раз создаются заново.

Comment: И если я правильно понимаю, то проблема заключается именно в том, чтобы создать результирующие файли с заголовком?

Comment: @Namerek  да ,  проблема и заключается именно в этом.

Comment: Посмотрите на ответ. Так понятно?

Comment: @Namerek  Спасибо за ответ,  я попробую это и отпишусь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import csv

headers = ['Name', 'Birthday', 'Height']

data = [
    ['Илья', '1999-12-02', '195'],
    ['Alex', '2000-05-11', '188']
]
# Если в данных есть кирилица и вы их потом собираетесь открывать в Excel
# То лучше используйте кодировку utf-8-sig и unix_dialect
with open('my.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as file:

    writer = csv.writer(file, dialect=csv.unix_dialect)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

```
"Name","Birthday","Height"
"Илья","1999-12-02","195"
"Alex","2000-05-11","188"
```

> Но если по честному, посмотрите на pandas, вы очень просто раскидаете по условиям по DataFrame и каждый из них сохраните хоть в excel хоть в csv хоть в json